# Error:premission denied to delete a couple of files

Tags: files

I'm trying to completely delete a program and its associated files to I can to a clean install, but it wont allow me too delete the final 4 files. Every time I try it gives me this,

```
    Error removing file /media/nunyah/bf8e3bed-a0b9-4929-b303-7d7c210aafa1/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-zesty-multiverse/64x64/steam-installer_steam.png: Permission denied
```

What should I do?

Comment: Permissions? Did you use 'sudo rm -rf'?

Comment: no i tried dragging them to the trash, and after it told me i couldn't do that i right clicked the programs and tried that way.

Comment: how would i use 'sudo rm -rf' to delete the programs ?

Answer (score 0):

The file you are trying to delete might have been being used by another program. If you sure it was not then open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and use:

```
sudo rm /media/nunyah/bf8e3bed-a0b9-4929-b303-d7c210aafa1/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-zesty-multiverse/64x64/steam-installer_steam.png
```

Please note anything starting with `/media` could be a SD Card mounted as read-only which means you can't delete it in the first place.

To close the terminal window you can click `X` on the window top corner, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or type `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Please let us know your progress because many people perform "drive byes". Welcome to **Ask Ubuntu** :)